# Empty graph. How to fix?

Tags: python, excel, charts

I create a dataframe from this [excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzZRB.png) using pandas. All it gave me was this [empty graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzZRB.png) that I made with Matplotlibs. What's wrong?

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st # Creates a website of the chart when I put streamlit run path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as ax
from PIL import Image

st.set_page_config(page_title='Charts')
st.header('Charts')
st.subheader('Bar Chart')

excel_file = r'C:\Users\CHIRASB1\Downloads\Chart.xlsm'
sheet_name = 'Sheet4'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,                # Reads the exel file and creates the dataframe
                   sheet_name = sheet_name,   # Calls the sheet obviously
                   usecols='A:Q', # Selects the columns of the part of the sheet I need
                   header=0, # Select the top of the section I need
                   dtype=str, # Makes the, all strings
                   nrows=18) # Selects the rows in the section I nee

y = df['1-Jun'].tolist()
x = df['Rule Exception Impacted Apps'].tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(x, y)
plt.plot()
plt.axis([1, 10, 0, 100])

plt.title('Total Rule Impacts vs. Date')       # Created the charts title
plt.ylabel("Total Rule Impacts")             # labels X-axis
plt.xlabel('Rules')                          # labels y-axis
plt.savefig('Chart.png') # creates a png file of the chart
image = Image.open('Chart.png')      # puts the png file on the streamlit website I made
st.image(image, caption='Uploaded Image.', use_column_width=True)
```

Comment: You never plot anything. All you do is set the axis limits, add a title, and add x- and y-labels.

Comment: I put plt.plot but nothing changed

Comment: 2 issues (that I found) : (1) `import matplotlib.pyplot as ax ` is redundant , should be removed. (2) at which line did u put the plt.plot? (pls [edit] to show the code update) (3) this is extra, but I always do this to test my own code.. try to print x & y values before plotting it.. if there is no value in x & y.. then empty plot is expected.

Comment: I put it right below df = pd.Dataframe()

Comment: I tried moving so it's above plt.savefig but that didn't change anything.